# Pyplot is plotting x-axis values wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

My X-axis values are

```
 ['0.00001','0.0001','0.001','0.01','0.1','1','10','100']
```

My Y-axis values are :

```
[0.15425122872713898, 0.14390317295797253, 0.12573138520177873, 0.0984319101273864, 0.07160052158213247, 0.1640810458390451, 0.21749306228894313, 0.21759336654518707]
```

I am trying to plot a scatter plot using the pyplot.scatter:

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

My output is:

[image: output]

'0.0001' value of x-axis is plotted in the '1' value of x-axis.
What is wrong with this?

Comment: I tried the code and works as expected (only one point at one).  Maybe a typo in your code?

Comment: Antonio I am still facing this issue. Any work around?

Comment: Don't use strings if you want to plot numbers.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest note that my X axis values must be those points only. If I use float numbers the scatter plot is not like the way I expected. X axis ranges from 0.00001 to 100.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. However I cannot reproduce this. For me the plot shows one scatter point per x axis category. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUev5.png). If you want people to find the error in your configuration you will need to provide a [mcve] and all the details about your installed versions etc.

Comment: @SanjeevRam I still don't understand what prevents you from using a logarithmic scale for your plot.